# Column Object Not Callable - using replace

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, replace, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I'm currently trying to convert an epoch date that is returned via an API call in some JSON. I'm attempting to tidy the field up but I've tried regex's etc. and get the same error so I've tried to do something basic.

This is an example of the dataframe at the moment

```
+--------+---------------------+
|d.userId|d.startDate          |
+--------+---------------------+
|60000033|/Date(1659398400000)/|
|100003  |/Date(1635724800000)/|
|2       |/Date(1672531200000)/|
|100010  |/Date(1635724800000)/|
```

This is the code which generates the above dataframe.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

jsonDF2 = jsonDF.withColumn('d', explode(col('d.results')))
jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select(jsonDF2.d.userId, jsonDF2.d.startDate)#.show(10, False)
```

The following line ends up with the error.

```py
jsonDF3 = jsonDF2.withColumn("startDate", col('startDate').replace("\Date(", "")).show(10, False)
```

> Column Object Not Callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to `replace` on the `Column` object. `Column` object does not have `replace` method. [These](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html) are the methods of `Column` class.

You probably wanted to use [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#replace) `replace` function. Sadly, it does not have DataFrame API. You can only access it using `expr`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

jsonDF2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(60000033, '/Date(1659398400000)/'),
     (100003, '/Date(1635724800000)/'),
     (2, '/Date(1672531200000)/'),
     (100010, '/Date(1635724800000)/')],
    ['d.userId', 'd.startDate']
)
jsonDF3 = jsonDF2.withColumn("startDate", F.expr("replace(`d.startDate`, '/Date(', '')"))

jsonDF3.show(truncate=0) 
# +--------+---------------------+---------------+
# |d.userId|d.startDate          |startDate      |
# +--------+---------------------+---------------+
# |60000033|/Date(1659398400000)/|1659398400000)/|
# |100003  |/Date(1635724800000)/|1635724800000)/|
# |2       |/Date(1672531200000)/|1672531200000)/|
# |100010  |/Date(1635724800000)/|1635724800000)/|
# +--------+---------------------+---------------+
```

However, `regexp_extract` would probably be a better choice:

```py
jsonDF3 = jsonDF2.withColumn("startDate", F.regexp_extract('`d.startDate`', '\d+', 0))
jsonDF3.show(truncate=0) 
# +--------+---------------------+-------------+
# |d.userId|d.startDate          |startDate    |
# +--------+---------------------+-------------+
# |60000033|/Date(1659398400000)/|1659398400000|
# |100003  |/Date(1635724800000)/|1635724800000|
# |2       |/Date(1672531200000)/|1672531200000|
# |100010  |/Date(1635724800000)/|1635724800000|
# +--------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

.replace is a python function not a pyspark df function use regexp_replace instead

```
jsonDF3 = jsonDF2.withColumn("startDate",regexp_replace(col('startDate'),"\d+","")).show(10,False)
```